# Нужна ли запятая во фразе: "Да(,) то и дело"?

Tags: пунктуация

По контексту это ответ пациента, жалующегося врачу на боль в груди, на вопрос, часто ли у пациента бывают ангины.

(Тут почему-то скрыли мой вопрос... Рискую ещё раз!)

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Не нужна запятая (усилительная частица; употребляется в начале предложения для придания высказыванию большей силы, выразительности [п. 6]).

*— Как часто вы болеете ангиной?

— Да то и дело.*

**2.** Нужна запятая (утвердительная частица; употребляется при ответе для выражения согласия, утверждения [п. 1]).

*— У вас ведь часто бывает ангина, да?

— Да, то и дело.*

Вместо запятой можно и точку поставить: *Да. То и дело.*

**3.** Дополнения

• **То и дело** — очень часто, регулярно, постоянно (устойчивое сочетание).

• [**Да**](https://rus-academic-dict.slovaronline.com/10891-%D0%B4%D0%B0) (МАС).

• Я не врач, и мне больше нравится единственное число слова "ангина".

Comment: Т. е. запятая одновременно  и нужна, и не нужна?)) — «Я не врач, и мне больше нравится единственное число слова "ангина"». — Мне ангина не нравится ни в каком виде)) но вообще это слово во множественном числе словари и литература разрешают без проблем: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0 — Он [Андрюша] жил в интернате, мёрз, беспрестанно болел ангинами и в первые месяцы очень хотел вернуться домой, к Бабане. — Д. И. Рубина, «Белая голубка Кордовы»

Comment: • Почему же *одновременно*, Егор? Вопросы-то ведь разные — и ответы, соответственно, пунктуационно разные. • Я не говорила, что мне нравится ангина и не утверждала, что множественное число не разрешено. • А немедицинская статистика Нацкорпуса такова: болел ангиной — 14, болел ангинами — 2 (в том числе и ваш пример).

Comment: «Вопросы-то ведь разные» — это почему? Оба варианта вполне могут быть ответами на один и тот же вопрос. Скажем: «Ангиной часто болеете?» «А немедицинская статистика Нацкорпуса такова: болел ангиной — 14, болел ангинами — 2». И? Это доказывает только то, что плюраль «ангины» нуждается в обосновании. Как, собственно, и любой плюраль.

Answer (score 0):

Возможны **варианты:**

(1) *Ангины? **Да, то и дело** бывают.* Да — утвердительное  слово (**согласие** при ответе).

(2)  *Ангины?  **Да то и дело** бывают!*  Да — **усилительная** частица.

Comment: Понимаю) А лично вам как больше нравится?

Comment: Мне нравится второй вариант.   Я сначала хотела предложить только этот вариант.   Он эмоциональный, что больше соответствует характеру оборота. https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkUqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCIgogCh4KA3JlcRIXChXQtNCwINGC0L4g0Lgg0LTQtdC70L4wAQ==

Comment: Ну, если человек страдает от боли, вся его эмоциональность может уйти на терпение... А вы вобще-то знаете такое слово: интонация?)

Comment: А то как же!  Вы паузы имеете в виду? Прочтение разное, безусловно. //Мой больной во втором варианте очень уж резвый получился, а на самом деле он вялый, конечно)

Comment: «Вы паузы имеете в виду?» — Я просто вспомнил, как тут недавно сомневались, что авторская речь, идущая после прямой, не обязательно должна начинаться со строчной буквы: никто ведь не написал, что какую-то роль здесь должна играть и интонация)

Comment: Интонация дело тонкое: как прочитал, такая и интонация) Если структура позволяет варианты при прочтении.

Comment: «кКак прочитал, такая и интонация». — Воот. А какая интонация — такая и пунктуация.